# CMS to work with 3rd party extensions

Tags: content-management-system

My question is how other Content Management Systems can work with extensions made by third-party developers?

I was reading through wordpress, joomla, drupal's code, but I need a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Basicly you need to have an API by which 3rd party delelopers can interact with your CMS, without breaking or hacking code of your "core". In Wordpress it was done by co-called "hooks" by which you inject some logic into the core modules, without actualy editing them. Everything depends on what type of 3rd party tools need to be developed: themes, plugins, hacks ect.